# How to collect dynamic html from input fields using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 16 table elements like,

```
<td id="test"> /Dynamic value appears here from JavaScript/ </td>
```

Where I put values from OnChange event, with this JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = value + " LT";
```

Now I want to know how to grab all input field values upon changing input field values in  `<td id="Test"> </td>` , because in the other field I want to show total amount based on other fields.

----------------------------------------------------------update
I will ask other question from same opera.

How get value from input type="hidden" field, where value changed allways then user select new element on html  ??

Comment: Can you show what content replaces with '/Dynamic value appears here from JavaScript/', without it no body understand how your are doing it.

Comment: Your IDs do not match. "Test" and "test".

Comment: To answer your updated question: use jQuery!:

`$('#hiddenField').val()` Just make sure you include the [jQuery library](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp) in the `head`.

Comment: But how to get value then it changed, without button?

Comment: $('#hiddenField').val() didint work bescause the value is changed by js

Comment: Are you still trying to find a solution to this problem? Your question is slightly confusing. It sounds like you want a user to click on an input field - like a radio button, inside each `<td>` element. When this happens, the value from this button will change the value of a hidden field, which you want to access later. Is this close at all?